# Quadratic polynomial

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Does there exist a rational quadratic polynomial of Sharkovskys type 2-infinity?

I agree with the answer of jc in the case of real polynomial, for this question  [Does there exist a real quadratic polynomial of Sharkovskys type 2-infinity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63441/does-there-exist-a-real-quadratic-polynomial-of-sharkovskys-type-2-infinity)

Comment: It is customary over here to invest a certain amount of care in the questions. 

Comment: This would seem to be a follow-up to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63441/does-there-exist-a-real-quadratic-polynomial-of-sharkovskys-type-2-infinity

Comment: Here it is quadratic polynomial with rational coefficient.

Comment: Unlikely. All such examples usually involve the Thue-Morse sequence, which usually leads to transcendental numbers. (Its binary sum is transcendental, say.) 